# В каких случаях в веб-программировании используются данные единицы измерения - px, CSS px, dip?

Tags: android, css, css3

Привет.

Запутался в вопросе, в каких случаях применяются эти единицы измерения - `px`, CSS `px`, `dip`.

[**Вот здесь**](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport?hl=ru) я прочитал, что

> **Аппаратно-независимый пиксель** (Device-independent pixel, `dip`):
>   результат масштабирования пикселей устройства до размеров опорного
>   пикселя для просмотра с нормального расстояния, представляет собой
>   примерно одну величину на всех устройствах. Ширина экрана iPhone 5
>   составляет 320 аппаратно-независимых пикселей.
>
> **Пиксель CSS**: единица, используемая для отображения страницы в области
>   просмотра. При указании размеров в стилях (например, width: 100`px`)
>   используются пиксели CSS. Отношение пикселей CSS к
>   аппаратно-независимым пикселям является коэффициентом масштабирования
>   страницы.

Но мне все равно непонятно, когда используется пиксель CSS, когда `dip`, а когда аппаратный пиксель.

Comment: **https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units**

Answer (score 8):

В CSS вы не работаете с абсолютными единицами измерения, никогда. Дюймы, сантиметры - не задаются. Пиксели - используются относительные. И em, rem, vw - тоже относительные величины.

Это нужно, потому что сайты мы можем смотреть с очень широкого ряда устройств. Чтобы сайт везде выглядел читабельно - производители устройств сами регулируют отношение аппаратных пикселей их экранов к CSS-пикселям.

Плотность пикселей (отношение разрешения экрана к реальному размеру экрана) влияет на CSS-пиксели. Чем выше плотность - тем больше на экране CSS-пикселей и больше места для расположения элементов.

Но на устройствах с retina-дисплеями делают исключение:

> Возьмем iPad с retina дисплеем. Фактическая его ширина в вертикальном положении - 1536 пикселей. Но размер экрана у него такой же, как и у не-retina версии. Поэтому для CSS устройство оставляет вдвое меньше пикселей, чем их на самом деле - 768 по ширине. Таким образом сайт, оптимизированный под не-retina iPad будет точно так же выглядеть и на retina iPad, верстка не поедет, потому что и в том, и в другом случае - CSS-ширина страницы 768 пикселей.

Также устройство может менять доступные CSS-пиксели для сайта при смене ориентации дисплея. Повернули планшет горизонтально - он сказал браузеру и сайту, что теперь по ширине у нас 1024 CSS-пикселей, а не 786, как было при вертикальной ориентации.

Еще вмешиваются браузеры. Когда мы делаем Zoom (масштабирование) страницы - фактически браузер говорит странице, что увеличилось или уменьшилось кол-во CSS-пикселей по ширине/высоте. Причем это свойственно только для desktop-браузеров. В частности поэтому, при адаптивной верстке, мы видим адаптацию при зуме страницы, а при зуме этой же страницы на мобильных устройствах и планшетах - не видим.

Comment: Тогда, возможно, отметите этот ответ как ответ? У вас из 16 вопросов только один отмечен, как отвеченный.

Comment: в этом ответе не сказано, когда используются пиксели "железа", когда - CSS-пиксели, а когда - dip-пиксели.

Comment: В css пиксели "железа" и dip-пиксели не используются никогда, и никогда не будут

Comment: я не про CSS, а вообще

Comment: в CSS-декларациях используются только CSS-пиксели. это мне понятно. вопрос был в том, КОГДА (в каких случаях) применяются эти разные виды пикселей.

Comment: тут есть чат, чтобы обсудить вопрос?

Comment: @Dimon, Вы написали в вопросе "_В каких случаях **в веб-программировании** используются ..._" что подразумевает CSS, а не "_вообще_"

Comment: то есть, веб-программист нигде не может использовать dip-пиксели в своем программировании?