# Вёрстка под большие экраны (телевизор, проектор), лучшие практики

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Какие вы используете методы при вёрстке под большие экраны. Если с планшетами и смартфонами всё понятно (@media), то как быть с очень большими экранами. Например, fullHD телевизор. В связи с тем, что там крупное "зерно", текст становится трудно читаемым. При этом на мониторе с тем же разрешением, всё выглядит отлично.

Другими словами я хочу, чтобы на FHD телевизоре страница выглядела как на FHD планшете а не FHD мониторе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В CSS нет возможности использовать реальные единицы измерения (см, дюймы), только относительные (css-пиксели тоже относительны). Устройства и браузеры ответственны за определение css-вьюпорта таким, чтобы сайт смотрелся на них читабельно. Подробнее об этом - в моем ответе к вопросу "[В каких случаях (и где) используются данные единицы измерения CSS - px, CSS px, dip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557229/217849)".

> С телевизорами проблема - они неадекватно определяют размер вьюпорта. Например, FullHD телевизор определяет вьюпорт как 1920*1080, хотя, с учетом размера экрана и средней дальностью экрана от зрителя - должен определять вьюпорт в районе 960*540, с плотностью пикселей равным двум.
>
> Оптимальный размер вьюпорта можно рассчитывать [здесь](https://patrickhlauke.github.io/web-tv/ideal-viewport/). А [здесь](http://viewportsizes.com/) можно изучить, какие размеры вьюпорта устройства ставят по стандарту.

Обычно мы доверяем определение размера вьюпорту устройству, вот таким кодом в `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Но на проблемных устройствах нужно корректировать размер вьюпорта самим. Это можно делать в js, таким образом:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]')
        .setAttribute('content', 'width='+width+
                                ',minimum-scale='+min_scale+
                                ',maximum-scale='+max_scale+
                                ',initial-scale='+init_scale);
```

Остается только научить сайт определять, на каком устройстве он запущен.

> Для этого есть `user-agent` браузера, и ширина/высота вьюпорта, определяемая устройством. Сопоставляя их, можно пытаться "угадать", какое устройство перед нами, и корректировать размер вьюпорта.

Существует плагин к [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) - [detectizr](http://baris.aydinoglu.info/Detectizr/), призванный проводить эти соответствия за вас, и выдающий на выходе устройство, его модель, браузер и другие характеристики. По ним можно определять проблемные для вашего сайта устройства, и корректировать для них размер вьюпорта, через js.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `<link rel="stylesheet" media="tv" href="example.css">`
Для определения размера используйте **[em](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)** или % вместо px. [**Инфо W3**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp). Остальные стили css3 применяйте как обычно.