# Как использовать dip-пиксели?

Tags: html, css

Как и когда использовать dip-пиксели? пишут, что надо указывать `dp` или `dip` прямо в коде вместо `px`. но, когда я пишу в CSS-декларации, например, `width:100dp;` или `width:100dip;`, то выдает ошибку.

Comment: Нет такой единицы. Возможно её хотели сделать, но сейчас px это именно абстрактные единицы, которые не связаны с физическим разрешением экрана.

Answer (score 2):

Интересно было бы взглянуть на книгу или туториал, в котором пишут подобное.

В CSS нет, и не будет, единиц `dp` и `dip`. Соглашения в CSS таковы, что использование `px` вполне обеспечивает независимость от пикселей конкретных устройств.

Подробно об этом я писал в вопросах:

- [В каких случаях (и где) используются данные единицы измерения CSS - px, CSS px, dip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557229/217849)
- [Вёрстка под большие экраны (телевизор, проектор), лучшие практики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/558278/217849)

Comment: http://css-live.ru/articles/materialnyj-dizajn-maket-edinicy-izmereniya-i-razmery.html видимо автор вопроса запутался. `dp` есть где-то в андроиде

Comment: я совсем запутался в этих пикселях. их несколько видов, и не понятно, какой именно из видов имеется в виду в конкретном случае. если это CSS-декларация, то имеются в виду CSS-пиксели. только это мне и понятно на данный момент. не понятно, в каких случаях имеются в виду пиксели "железа" (физические пиксели). не понятно, в каких случаях имеется в виду пиксели dip

Comment: тут есть чат, чтобы обсудить вопрос, не используя комментарии?