# Почему у iPhone 5 выдает ширину 320 пикселей?

Tags: css, iphone

Я написал простой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                       
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
   *{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #div{
    height:91px;
    width:320px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
   }
   
   body{
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <div id="div">hello</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

У меня стоит 20 дюймовый монитор, хочу на нем эмулировать, как айфон отображает. Для этого в девтулс захожу и на значок телефона переключаю - адаптивная верстка.

Ширина красного квадрата в CSS-пикселях составляет 320. Я думал, что ширина айфона 5 бует 640 пикселей - "железных" пикселей. Но выдало только 320 непонятно каких пикселей. Что это за число? Получается, что красный квадрат с шириной в 320 CSS-пикселей равен ширине айфона 5 с шириной 320 каких-то (КАКИХ - пикселей железа, КСС-пикселей или dip-пикселей?) пикселей . Почему так? Я привык работать на 20 дюймовом мониторе, и когда я пишу window.screen.width, то мне выдает 1600 пикселей железа. Но, эмулируя айфон5, я пишу window.screen.width и получаю опять те же 320 пикселей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

есть понятие аппаратного пикселя, который на разных устройствах имеет разный размер. а есть понятие аппаратно-независимого (тот, который на разных устройствах имеет одинаковый размер) вот 320 px это последнее. а 620 это сколько физических пикселей имеет в ширину смартфон.
подробнее :

https://habrahabr.ru/post/145619/

Comment: не понимаю, как могут использоваться одновременно два вида оптических пикселей - CSS-пиксели и dip-пиксели. window.screen.width выдает, насколько я понимаю, 320 dip-пикселей, если эмулировать айфон 5 в девтулс.

Answer (score 2):

Также Вы можете глянуть [эту статью](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) где наглядно в иллюстрациях демонстрируется как из 320х568 points получается изображение на физических 640х1136.

Если кратко - изначально имеется абстрактный дисплей с абстрактными координатами(points). Затем они рендерятся в пиксели на физическом устройстве. Эти координаты умножаются на множитель (х1 для iPhone 2G, 3g, 3GS; x2 iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5C, 5S, SE, 6, 6S; x3 iPhone 6/6S Plus. Вскоре список пополнится новыми моделями) и получается наше физическое разрешение дисплея. В некоторых случаях после перемножения затем происходит уменьшение изображения.

Comment: не понимаю, как могут использоваться одновременно два вида оптических пикселей - CSS-пиксели и dip-пиксели. window.screen.width выдает, насколько я понимаю, 320 dip-пикселей, если эмулировать айфон 5 в девтулс.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, внимательно прочтите ответы на свои же предыдущие вопросы:

- [В каких случаях (и где) используются данные единицы измерения CSS - px, CSS px, dip?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/557229/217849)
- [Как использовать dip-пиксели?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559327/217849)

А также мой ответ на этот вопрос:

- [Вёрстка под большие экраны (телевизор, проектор), лучшие практики](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/558278/217849)

В частности, в ответах вы увидите, что:

> Возьмем iPad с retina дисплеем. **Фактическая его ширина** в вертикальном положении - **1536 пикселей**. Но размер экрана у него такой же, как и у не-retina версии. Поэтому **для CSS устройство оставляет вдвое меньше пикселей**, чем их на самом деле - **768 по ширине**.

Я крайне рекомендую вам выкинуть то, что вы читаете, и переключиться на другую книгу или туториал - потому что данный туториал вызвал у вас путаницу в понятиях, и мешает нормально развиваться в верстке.